# Erro de constraint no PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraint

Tenho um código que está dando o seguinte erro:

> there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table
>   "horario"

Código:

```sql
CREATE TYPE weekday AS ENUM ('Domingo', 'Segunda', 'Terça', 'Quarta', 'Quinta', 'Sexta', 'Sabado');

-- Table Turma
CREATE TABLE TURMA
(
  codigoTurma serial PRIMARY KEY,
  nome character varying(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

-- Table Horario
CREATE TABLE HORARIO
(
  diaSemana weekday,
  hora time,

  PRIMARY KEY(diaSemana, hora)
);

-- Table: Horario Turma
create table HORARIOTURMA(

   codigoTurma serial REFERENCES TURMA(codigoTurma),
   diaSemana weekday  REFERENCES HORARIO(diaSemana),
   hora time          REFERENCES HORARIO(hora),

   PRIMARY KEY (codigoTurma, diaSemana, hora)
);
```

O que pode estar gerando este erro?

Answer (score 1):

O **erro está na criação da chave estrangeira da tabela "HORARIOTURMA"** que está relacionada com a tabela "HORARIO"

A chave primária da tabela "HORARIO" é composta por duas colunas (diaSemana, hora) logo a chave estrangeira da tabela "HORARIOTURMA" deve referenciar estas duas colunas.

```
CREATE TABLE HORARIOTURMA(
   codigoTurma serial ,
   diaSemana weekday  ,
   hora time          ,
   PRIMARY KEY (codigoTurma, diaSemana, hora),
   FOREIGN KEY (codigoTurma) REFERENCES TURMA (codigoTurma),   
   FOREIGN KEY (diaSemana, hora) REFERENCES HORARIO (diaSemana, hora)
);
```